# Getting the ipv4 of my machine using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I got this code to get the IPV4 of my computer

```
        Dim tmpHostName As String = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()
        Label3.Text = System.Net.Dns.GetHostByName(tmpHostName).AddressList(0).ToString()
```

But then i got a warning that i should replace GetHostByName to GetHostEntry
The could works. but i'm worried about that warning. What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get host entry using host name:

```
Dim hostEntry As IPHostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName())
```

And after it you can get ipv4 of your computer from address list using the following code:

```
hostEntry.AddressList.FirstOrDefault(Function(i As IPAddress) Not i.IsIPv6LinkLocal AndAlso Not i.IsIPv6Multicast AndAlso Not i.IsIPv6SiteLocal)
```